# reading a variable and searching if and then statement to match something in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, string-comparison

Hi I Have a command/function is a script  that assigns users names to variable
so:

```
var1=dedwards torontobgs NJVMTTS2 srounce jstickler
echo $var1 produces >>  dedwards torontobgs NJVMTTS2 srounce jstickler
```

How can I write a command to see if the userid "NJVMTTS2" exist in the variable ? It seems that variable is treated as one string and not individual string?

I know this is simple but cannot get it to work
What I want to do is as follow:

if $1 ( passed by anther function ) exist in $VAR1 
then do something

```
so if $1 = NJVMTTS2
and if NJVMTTS2 contained in the $VAR1
Then do echo "yes"  else echo "no"
```

Comment: Without quotes that first line produces an error.

Answer (score 1):

Just standard pattern matching.

```
var1='dedwards torontobgs NJVMTTS2 srounce jstickler'
if [[ $var1 = *NJVMTTS2* ]]; then
  …
fi
```

Or, for portability:

```
case "$var1" in
  *NJVMTTS2*) …;;
esac
```

### Update

if NJVMTTS2 is in a parameter, you should quote the parameter expansion, but you must be careful not to quote the pattern:

```
case "$var1" in
  *"$1"*) …;;
esac
```

Comment: @theuniverseisflat OK, I took a wild guess what the problem is and updated my answer. It would save everyone some time if you would describe fully what you are doing in your question.

Answer (score 0):

First, your assignment should be quoted, otherwise var1 will contain only the first word.

```
var1="dedwards torontobgs NJVMTTS2 srounce jstickler"
```

Then you can grep for the name inside the variable:

```
if echo $var1 | grep '\bNJVMTTS2\b' >/dev/null; then echo Found it; fi
```

The `\b` word boundary symbols make sure you look for the whole word, thus matching `NJVMTTS2` but not `fooNJVMTTS2bar`

If `fooNJVMTTS2bar` is also OK, the other answer will work. @Kojiro's solution also has the advantage that it does not use an external program, it's pure shell.

Comment: Not working .. I want to actually do this   if var1 contains any entry that matches $1 ( passed by another function ) then echo found it